# CMake failed to detect installed OpenSSL which was compiled from source

Tags: aix, openssl, cmake

I am trying to compile Hadoop 3.2.0 from source on AIX 7.1 as the pre-built 32-bit binary is incompatible with the 64-bit machine we are using.

The OpenSSL is built from source so I have both the developmental headers and the compiled binaries. However, no matter what I do CMake does not seem to be able to detect the installed open ssl.

The `openssl` binary is located in `/usr/local/bin` and the raw code is located in `/usr/openssl/openssl-master`

```
CUSTOM_OPENSSL_PREFIX = /usr/local
Cannot find a usable OpenSSL library. OPENSSL_LIBRARY=OPENSSL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND, OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include, CUSTOM_OPENSSL_LIB=/usr/openssl/openssl-master, CUSTOM_OPENSSL_PREFIX=/usr/local, CUSTOM_OPENSSL_INCLUDE=
```

Comment: Perhaps you didn't do a proper 'make install' in the openssl source directory, only manually copied the binary executable into /usr/local/bin